# Invalid use of incomplete type struct std::hash with unordered_map with std::pair of enum class as key

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map, enum-class

I want to use a `unordered_map<std::pair<enum_class,other_enum_class>,std::uint8_t>` for managing some pixelmap formats.

Here the minimal code :

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdint> 
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

enum class PNM : std::uint8_t { PBM, PGM, PPM };
enum class Format : bool      { BIN, ASCII };

struct pair_hash {
public:
    template <typename T, typename U>
    std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<T, U> &x) const { 
        return std::hash<T>()(x.first) ^ std::hash<U>()(x.second); 
    }
};

int main(){

    std::unordered_map<std::pair<PNM, Format>, std::uint8_t, pair_hash> k_magic_number ({
        { { PNM::PBM, Format::BIN   }, 1 }, { { PNM::PGM, Format::BIN   }, 2 }, { { PNM::PPM, Format::BIN   }, 3 },
        { { PNM::PBM, Format::ASCII }, 4 }, { { PNM::PGM, Format::ASCII }, 5 }, { { PNM::PPM, Format::ASCII }, 6 }
    });

    std::cout << k_magic_number[std::make_pair<PNM, Format>(PNM::PBM, Format::BIN)];
}
```

With GCC I have an [error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2282aee6b7b7527a) when I try to instantiate the class :

> main.cpp:14:24: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct std::hash'
>      return std::hash()(x.first) ^ std::hash()(x.second);
>   In file included from
>   /usr/local/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:5469:0,
>                    from /usr/local/include/c++/5.2.0/string:52,
>   [...]

With Clang I also have an [error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5b13e61a5e141a3) :

> error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::hash'
>                   return std::hash()(x.first) ^ std::hash()(x.second); 
>   /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.2.0/../../../../include/c++/5.2.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1257:16:
>   note: in instantiation of function template specialization
>   'pair_hash::operator()' requested here
>   [...]

With VS2013 I have no error and the code compile and executes.

What is missing in my code ?

Comment: Depending on your need, you can also consider using std::map, which does not have the hashing requirement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

g++-5 gives following errors:

> invalid use of incomplete type `struct std::hash<PNM>`
>
> invalid use of incomplete type `struct std::hash<Format>`

So, you should just specialize `std::hash` for `PNM` and `Format`.

```
namespace std {
template<>
struct hash<PNM>
{
   typedef PNR argument_type;
   typedef size_t result_type;

   result_type operator () (const argument_type& x) const
   {
      using type = typename std::underlying_type<argument_type>::type;
      return std::hash<type>()(static_cast<type>(x));
   }
};

template<>
struct hash<Format>
{
   typedef Format argument_type;
   typedef size_t result_type;       

   result_type operator () (const argument_type& x) const
   {
      using type = typename std::underlying_type<argument_type>::type;
      return std::hash<type>()(static_cast<type>(x));
   }
};

}
```

Or you can write template struct, that will works only for `enums` with use of SFINAE (not sure, that it's not UB by standard, since it's not specialization actually).

```
namespace std
{

template<typename E>
struct hash
{
   typedef E argument_type;
   typedef size_t result_type;
   using sfinae = typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<E>::value>::type;
     
   result_type operator() (const E& e) const
   {
      using base_t = typename std::underlying_type<E>::type;
      return std::hash<base_t>()(static_cast<base_t>(e));
   }
};

}
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try that aren't these supposed to already have a specialization since there are basically bools and integers ?

Comment: @coincoin they are `enum classes `, that is different type from int.

Comment: Thanks @ForEveR this [compiles and executes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42a6f4e7505f70a1). But how come my `std::cout` is not printed ?

Comment: @coincoin: it is, but ASCII code 1 isn't a "printable" (visible) character - it's a control code that terminals and that web site don't necessarily show in any useful way.  Try `cout << (int)...` to cast it to `int` such that the ASCII value is shown.